# Is it possible to append an entire php partial view via JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently creating a really simple JQuery function which will append a large block of html on click. However i find it really messy to just store the large block of html in a variable `var html = '<div> large block of html</div>'`.

I want to avoid that and i was wondering if it is possible via JQuery / JQuery Ajax to just the call the blade.php partial view and Append it to to the div container.

Enlighten me ;)

Comment: What about to include `blade.php` with php instead of jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be something like this.

Return the HTML "block" as string on the blade.php site.
Call the blade.php via jQuery / AJAX call and then append it to whatever div it belongs to.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "localhost/blade.php",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).appendTo('body)');
        }
    });
```

blade.php could look like this.

```
$veryLongString ='<div>abc</div>';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
 echo $veryLongString;}
```